# Generalized reaction rate and derivation

Tags: physical-chemistry, kinetics, molecular-dynamics

Most textbooks give the reaction rate

$$r = k C_\ce{A}^a C_\ce{B}^b  \tag{1}$$

for the elementary process $\ce{a A + b B -> P}$. However, expression (1) is not valid in the general case: e.g. it is lacking fluctuations, small-size corrections, memory effects, relativistic corrections,...

I have seen some derivations of the rate expression (1) using kinetic theory, Langevin approach, or chemical master equation, but the derivations introduced further approximations: e.g. the kinetic theory approach considered only binary collisions in diluted gases under local thermodynamic equilibrium.

Consider the process $\ce{A -> P}$, according to (1) the rate expression would be

$$r = k C_\ce{A}  \tag{2}$$

However this expression not only predicts an incorrect stationary state, but it does not represent the real concentration in the system, because $C_\ce{A}$ is only an averaged concentration and not the instantaneous concentration of species $\ce{A}$ in the system. In a first approach the above rate is replaced by

$$r = k \tilde{C}_\ce{A} + \tilde{f} \tag{3}$$

where $\tilde{C}_\ce{A}$ represents the real concentration in the system and $\tilde{f}$ is a stochastic chemical 'force'. Now (3) represents the rate of the real concentration and it gives the correct stationary limit. (3) satisfies a fluctuations-dissipation theorem that relates $\langle\tilde{f}(t)\tilde{f}(t')\rangle$ to the rate constant $k$. This relation is used in experimental methods that measure chemical fluctuations to obtain the rate constant.

Equation (3) continues being an approximation, a generalization could be the introduction of memory effects, which could give something as

$$r = \int_0^t \kappa(s) \tilde{C}_\ce{A}(t-s) ds + \tilde{F} \tag{4}$$

where the kernel $\kappa$ and the generalized stochastic 'force' $\tilde{F}$ have complex expressions, but (4) continues being an approximation. Consider now the process $\ce{2A -> P}$, according to (1) the rate expression would be

$$r = k C_\ce{A}^2  \tag{5}$$

but this is not correct in general. Introduce the volume factors into $k$ to obtain

$$r = K N_\ce{A}^2  \tag{6}$$

and you can check this predicts a rate $r=K$ when $N_\ce{A}=1$, which is obviously impossible because at least two molecules are needed for the step. The rate (6) is invalid for mesoscopic systems (e.g. reactions involving small amounts of matter in living cells) and it is also incorrect for large systems in the long time limit, when $N_\ce{A} \rightarrow 0$. A corrected rate is given by

$$r = K N_\ce{A} (N_\ce{A} -1)  \tag{7}$$

which cannot be derived from (1). However, (7) can be derived in combinatorial kinetics, which postulates the next rate expression for an elementary process $\ce{a A + b B -> P}$

$$r = K \frac{N_\ce{A}!}{(N_\ce{A} - a)!} \frac{N_\ce{B}!}{(N_\ce{B} - b)!}  \tag{8}$$

But again (8) is an approximation.

Each rate expression I find in the literature is valid only for some specific cases, but fails for others.

What is the **general** expression for the reaction rate for an elementary process and how can the expression be **derived** from first-principles?

Comment: What you've written is a macroscopic observable, so it *is* the general expression, and it is generally valid for the class of reactions for which it is designed (which is a bit circular, I realize, but that's the nature of empirical statements).  All the complications of which you speak vanish in the thermodynamic limit.  It sounds like what you're after is some kind of kinetic theory expression, and you're unsatisfied with dilute gas approximations, so maybe the place to start is with general formulations in the liquid state like http://rspa.royalsocietypublishing.org/content/188/1012/10

Comment: Read my answer to this question https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/81019/why-is-the-rate-of-a-reaction-proportional-to-the-concentrations-of-reactants-ra as it largely covers the points you raise

Comment: @ChristopherGrayce I didn't write a macroscopic observable ($r$ could be a mesoscopic rate) and the thermodynamic limit is an approximation used to simplify some formulas, but no real system has infinite volume and infinite number of particles. I am realy looking for a dynamical rate expression, not a kinetic one, but will look the reference. Thanks

Comment: @porphyrin The first part of your answer uses collision theory with the usual simplifications (including the one that I mentioned explicitly as "local thermodynamic equilibrium"). The second part mentions the approach taken by Gillespie, which is based in chemical master equation (I also mentioned this equation) which built in many simplifications including the ignoring of non-Markovian effects in the system.

Comment: Ok, I assume also that you know the book by Erdi & Toth (Math models of chem reactions) then in that case you should probably start by calculating reaction dynamics trajectories where you can control all parameters then average over quantum states at your choice of energy distribution.

Comment: @ChristopherGrayce The paper you gave is the original BBGKY approach. Besides this approach focusing on the distribution function (I am asking about the observables), the approach was shown to break in certain dense situations in the sixties, because the approach assumes an analyticity condition for the transport coefficients that is not generally valid.

Comment: @porphyrin I cannot access that book, but I checked the TOC and read some open chapters in GoogleBooks. I didn't find a general rate expression without the limitations mentioned in my question. It has been some time since my last check of reaction dynamics literature, but I recall authors then just assuming some simplified rate equation e.g. (1) and then using approx quantum evolution methods such S-matrix to obtain k for specific systems.

Comment: You can calculate anything from the distribution functions.  If you don't know how, perhaps you need to take a step back and study some more basic statistical mechanics.  Try Hansen & McDonald's classic book on the subject, extremely accessible and clear.

Comment: @ChristopherGrayce If you know the answer to the question you could just put it here instead make the partridge dizzy.

Comment: If I knew the answer to the question I would write a paper and send it to PNAS or Physical Review and become famous.