# Why isn't the ion-product constant the sum of the molar concentrations of H+ and OH-?

Tags: acid-base

The Chemistry texts I have present the ion-product constant as:

$$K_\mathrm w= 1.0 \times 10^{-14} = [\ce{H+}][\ce{OH-}]$$

Additionally I'm told that this constant at (25 °C) is an equilibrium. As one concentration rises, the other declines.

It seems easy to imagine a constant as a sum which the $[\ce{H+}]$ and the $[\ce{OH-}]$ concentrations add up to in a mixture but it's very difficult for me to grasp the idea that they are a product of multiplication.

What am I missing here?