# Derivation of relationship betwee standard Gibbs energy of reaction and equilibrium constant?

Tags: thermodynamics, equilibrium, free-energy

How does one derive $\Delta_\mathrm r G^\circ = -RT\ln(K)$? I don't see the connection mathematically *or* conceptually; how does Gibbs at all relate to the equilibrium constant of a reaction?

This was part one of a three part question which I've split into 3 individual questions as advised. I left this question as the one associated with the original title; the other one is [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/114655/gibbs-free-energy-notation)  and I will edit the third in when my post cooldown allows me to post it, if anyone wishes to visit those as well now.

Comment: @KarstenTheis The question has been split, as requested.

Comment: Related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/104950/how-to-derive-the-relation-between-gibbs-energy-and-equilibrium-constant/104964#104964]